# Why don't the button inside the table is getting the value of a td upon clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, datatables

I have filled a table, actually a jquery data table. I have created a button by appending it to **td** by looping over. The button calls **showmsg()** function successfully but can't get the value from a specific **td** of the row it is in.

It says **undefined**.

Code:

Function that fill table and created an EDIT button inside it.

```
 function fillServicesGrid()
        {

            var url = '@Url.Action("GetServices")';
            var data = ''

            $.get(url, data, function (response) {

                $("#tblServices").html("");

                $.each(response, function (i, val) {
                    $("#tblServices").append($('<tr>').append($('<td id="tdServiceID">').html(val.ServiceID)).append($('<td>').html(val.ServiceName)).append($('<td>').html(val.ServicePrice)).append($('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnEdit" onclick="showmsg();">Edit</button>')));
                });

            });

            $('#tblServices').DataTable();

            $('.sorting_asc, .sorting').addClass('datatable-headerrow');
            $('.paginate_button.current').addClass('pagination-buttons');
            $('.dataTables_filter, .dataTables_length').hide();

        }
```

a function that is getting called by btnEdit to get the text of a td #tdService

```
function showmsg()
{
    var serviceID = $(this).closest('tr').find('#tdServiceID').text();
    alert(serviceID);



    $("#ServiceName").val("Tester");
    $("#ServicePrice").val("Testing");
}
```

Comment: Is this code in a razor or js file? Is the id unique? What calls showmsg - is `this` what you think it is? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: You aren't supposed to use ids when it applies to multiple DOM elements. Try changing <td id="tdServiceID"> to <td class="tdServiceID"> and in the function showmsg, var serviceID = $(this).closest('tr').find('.tdServiceID').text();

Comment: @Amit: not working

Comment: @Pete: it's in razor, locally. Yes, the id is unique,

Comment: I have been trying to solve it but no way, help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Ids for the html elements they should be unique. Try doing the following in your `each` function:

```
 $("#tblServices").append($('<tr>').append($('<td>').attr('id',"tdServiceID" + i).html(val.ServiceID)).append($('<td>').html(val.ServiceName)).append($('<td>').html(val.ServicePrice)).append($('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnEdit" onclick="showmsg(\'' + i + '\');">Edit</button>')));
```

(setting the Id to be tdServiceID appending the index of the iteration)
Note that we are passing the 'i' in the showmsg function which can now become

```
function showmsg(i)
{
    var serviceID = $('#tdServiceID'+i).text();
    alert(serviceID);

    $("#ServiceName").val("Tester");
    $("#ServicePrice").val("Testing");
}
```

It seems to be working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwmy3r5v/)

Not sure what the last two lines in that method should be doing

Comment: thanks a lot, it works but still i don't understand how ? :P

Comment: what is it that you don't understand? maybe we could continue in a chat?